# Trying to download data from URL with CSV File

Tags: python

I'm slightly new to Python and have a question as to why the following code doesn't produce any output in the `csv` file. The code is as follows:

```
import csv
import urllib2

url = 'http://www.rba.gov.au/statistics/tables/csv/f17-yields.csv'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
cr = csv.reader(response)

for row in cr:
    with open("AusCentralbank.csv", "wb") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(row)
```

Cheers.

**Edit**:

Brien and Albert solved the initial issue I had. However, I now have one further question. When I download the CSV File which I have listed above which is in "http://www.rba.gov.au/statistics/tables/#interest-rates" under Zero-coupon "Interest Rates - Analytical Series - 2009 to Current - F17" and is the F-17 Yields CSV I see that it has 5 workbooks and I actually just want to gather the data in the 5th Workbook. Is there a way I could do this? Cheers.

Comment: you should look at using [**requests**](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) instead of urllib2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@albert had a great answer.  I've gone ahead and converted it to the equivalent Python 2.x code.  You were doing a bit too much work in your original program; since the file was already a csv you didn't need to do any special work to turn it into a csv.

```
import urllib2

url = 'http://www.rba.gov.au/statistics/tables/csv/f17-yields.csv'

response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html = response.read()

with open('AusCentralbank.csv', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(html)
```

Comment: Sorry. I actually have one more request with regards to my initial Question. I have edited the original question to include this.

Comment: At this point I would create a new question for it.  I don't really think anyone besides me will see this since the question is old and marked as complete.  I'm not sure of a way to do what you've requested.

Answer (score 7):

I could only test my code using Python 3. However, the only diffence should be [`urllib2`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen), hence I am using [`urllib.respose`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen) for opening the desired url.

The variable `html` is type `bytes` and can generally be written to a file in binary mode. Additionally, your source is a csv-file already, so there should be no need to convert it somehow:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8

import urllib

url = 'http://www.rba.gov.au/statistics/tables/csv/f17-yields.csv'

response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
html = response.read()

with open('output.csv', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(html)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have made an addition to my initial question and was wondering if I could get your help. Thanks

Comment: Please open a new question since this is not a forum but a question and answer platform. Keep in mind to provide a link to data you have problems with. However, I could not find the mentioned five workbooks in the csv-file(http://www.rba.gov.au/statistics/tables/csv/f17-yields.csv). The Excel-File has four workbooks containing the data of those three csv-files and additional notes.

Answer (score 3):

It is probably because of your opening mode.

According to [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files):

> 'w' for only writing (an existing file with the same name will be
>   erased)

You should use append(`a`) mode to append it to the end of the file.

> 'a' opens the file for appending; any data written to the file is
>   automatically added to the end.

Also, since the file you are trying to download is csv file, you don't need to convert it.

Comment: I changed it to `with open("AusCentralbank.csv", "wb") as f`, yet I still don't get anyoutput in the CSV File. Do you know why this could be?

Comment: You have a few issues with the way you've set up your program.  See my or @albert's answer for a more complete way of doing things.

Comment: You re-open (i.e., destroy) your output file for every row of input. You end up with a probably empty row...